# Print data grid view data in two printer?

Tags: c#, printing

I want to print some data in printer 1 and some data in printer 2.

```
public void printkot()
        {
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
            PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
            Font font = new Font("Arial", 12);
            PaperSize psize = new PaperSize("Custome", 314, 500);
            pd.Document = pdoc;
            for (int ch = 0; dataGridView1.Rows.Count > ch; ch++)
            {

                if (dataGridView1.Rows[ch].Cells["calkot_print"].Value.ToString() == "K1")
                {
                    pdoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "KOT";
                    pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);

                }

            }
            pd.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height = 500;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width = 314;

            if (pdoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
            {
                pdoc.Print();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Printer is invalid.");
            }

        }
        private void printDocument1_PrintPage2(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {

            string table_no;
            table_no = lbltable.Text;
            float xs = 10;
            float ys = 5;
            float widths = 285.0F; // max width I found through trial and error
            float heights = 0F;
            DataTable dtm = blu.checkbusiness();
            Font drawFontArial12Bold = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            Font drawFontArial10Regular = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular);
            Font drawFontArial10Regularsmall = new Font("Arial", 6, FontStyle.Regular);
            SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            Pen drawingPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
            // Set format of string.
            StringFormat drawFormatCenter = new StringFormat();
            drawFormatCenter.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            StringFormat drawFormatLeft = new StringFormat();
            drawFormatLeft.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            StringFormat drawFormatRight = new StringFormat();
            drawFormatRight.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            StringFormat drawFormatRightlest = new StringFormat();
            string business_name = dtm.Rows[0]["business_name"].ToString();
            string address = dtm.Rows[0]["address"].ToString();
            Graphics gra = e.Graphics;
            String strDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            gra.DrawString(strDate, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 10, 60);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(business_name, drawFontArial12Bold, drawBrush, new RectangleF(xs, ys, widths, heights), drawFormatCenter);
            ys += e.Graphics.MeasureString(business_name, drawFontArial12Bold).Height;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(address, drawFontArial10Regular, drawBrush, new RectangleF(xs, ys, widths, heights), drawFormatCenter);
            ys += e.Graphics.MeasureString(address, drawFontArial10Regular).Height;
            gra.DrawString("Table No::", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 190, 60);
            gra.DrawString(table_no, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 250, 45);

            gra.DrawLine(drawingPen, 10, 75, 309, 75);
            gra.DrawString("Item", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 30, 75);
            gra.DrawString("Qty", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 220, 75);
            gra.DrawLine(drawingPen, 10, 90, 309, 90);
            int y;
            y = 95;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                string item_name = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["cal_item_name"].Value.ToString();
                string quantity = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["cal_qty"].Value.ToString();
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["calkot_print"].Value.ToString() == "K2")
                {
                    gra.DrawString(item_name.ToString(), new System.Drawing.Font("Time New Roamn", 9, FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 30, y);
                    gra.DrawString(quantity, new System.Drawing.Font("Time New Roamn", 9, FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 220, y);
                    y = y + 15;
                }


            }
            int z = y + 20;
            gra.DrawLine(drawingPen, 10, z, 309, z);
            gra.DrawString("Description", new System.Drawing.Font("Time New Roamn", 9, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 10, z + 5);
            gra.DrawString(txtrichbox.Text, new System.Drawing.Font("Time New Roamn", 7, FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), 10, z + 20);

            z = y + 20;
        }
```